# Ascending chain - Isomorphism theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

So that what I did so far :

**Interesting results :**

1. $f$ is injective $\iff$ $\ker f = \{0\}$
2. $\ker f$ is a submodule of $X$
3. As $X$ is noetherian, then each ascending chain $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \dots$ has the property that there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M_k = M_{k+1}= M_{k+2}= \dots$

So in considering those results, suppose that $f$ is non injective. The objective is to construct an ascending chain doesn't having the property $3$.

Let $M_1= \ker f$. Then we have $M_1 \subset X \subset Y$. According to the first isomorphism theorem $X/M_1 \cong f(X)=Y$. Furthermore, I have the intuition we could use the correspondance theorem, i.e. we have that the submodules of $X$ containing $M_1$ are in correspondance with the submodules of $X/M_1$ (i.e. $K \subset K'$, where $K, K' \supset N_1 \iff K'/M_1 \subset K / M_1$).

I would like to continue the construction of this chain, but I am blocked. Is anyone could give me a hint how could I continue this problem? I think I have to consider the composition of the function $f$ with itself, but it is unclear.

Thanks!

P.S. Please don't give me more than a good hint to continue.

Comment: Hint: look at the preimage of $M_1$. What happens to it when we apply f twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMSmath}$
You are on the right track in wanting to consider the composition of $f$ with itself.

Knowing $f: X\to Y$ is surjective, consider $f^{-1}(X) \subset X$. Notice that ker$(f) \subset f^{-1}(X)$. Applying $f$ again (to the $X$ in the image of the first application of $f$) gives a map from $f^{-1}(X)$. 
$$X \xrightarrow{f} Y\supset X\xrightarrow{f}Y$$

The important part: the kernel of this new map contains the kernel of $f$. To build an ascending chain, we take a similar repeated application of $f$:

$$X \xrightarrow{f} Y\supset X\xrightarrow{f}Y\supset X\xrightarrow{f}Y\supset X\xrightarrow{f}...$$

Composing these together, we get a series of functions $f$, $f^2$, $f^3$... from the first $X$ in the sequence, and we can show that the kernels form an ascending chain in $X$. The kernel of the second application of $f$, for example, contains the 0 element in $Y$, and the preimage of that element is exactly ker$(f)$. We know that $f$ fails to be injective in all these applications, so that ker$(f^n)\subset $ ker$(f^{n+1})$ $\forall n\ge 1$. Accordingly, we have the ascending chain ker$(f)\subset$ ker$(f^2)\subset$ ker$(f^3)$...

Comment: I've added some details to the answer. Let me know if there's anything further that I should include.

Comment: Could you explain why $ \ker(f)⊂f^{−1}(X)$ and why "the kernel of this new map contains the kernel to f"?

Comment: @RobertDavis  $ \ker(f)\subset f^{−1}(X)$ simply because $0\in X$, so if something is sent to zero, it is also sent to X. to see that the kernel of the map $f^2$ contains the kernel of $f$, think of $f^2$ in terms of its two component maps. First we apply $f$, and the elements in ker$(f)$ are sent to 0. Next, we apply $f$ again, to the copy of $X$ *in the image* of the first application of $f$. We know that this map will take 0 to 0, so thinking of the composition of the two maps, ker$(f)$ first goes 0 which then goes to 0 again, so that ker$(f)$ will be in the kernel of the composition $f^2$.

Comment: @RobertDavis The point of that statement is to make sure that the ascending chain doesn't satisfy the condition you described in a noetherian ring. We want $\text{ker}(f^n)$ to be *properly* contained in ker$(f^{n+1})$. But we're just recycling the same map $f$, so the $n$th application still won't be injective, and the kernel (just of that $f$, not yet considering the composition) will be nontrivial. Knowing this, we can say that ker$(f^{n})\subset$ ker$(f^{n+1})$ by essentially the same argument I used in my last comment.